# How do I access a member tab of a QTabWidget class by using a variable name?

Tags: c++, qt

In a function I am currently working on, I am creating a multi-dimensional array of checkboxes, with the dimensions specified at run-time by the user. In order to represent the 'z' dimension, I create multiple tabs -- each one representing a different dimension -- and create an array of check boxes in each tab. The tabs are labeled dim1, dim2, dim3, ... etc.

The problem I am having is the fact that in order to create the array of check boxes (within 3 'for' loops), I have to call the tabs as follows:

```
checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( ui->dim1 ));
```

Where checkBoxVector holds pointers to the checkboxes. Now my first thought was that I would simply create a variable name that would change with each loop. With each iteration, it would go: "dim1", then "dim2", "dim3", ... etc. The problem with this is that I cannot reference the tabs with a string variable, I must type in the actual name of the tab. Here is a sample of that code:

```
int num = k+1;
QString dim = "dim";
QString tab_name = dim.append(QString("%1").arg(num));
checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( ui->tab_name ));
```

This gives me the error " 'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'tab_name' ".

Therefore; my question is: how can I apply this idea of changing the NAME of the tab with each loop, without causing such an error?

EDIT: I think I forgot to mention that the tabs have already been created at this point, and have already been labeled with the "dim1", "dim2", "dim3", ... names. The only issue I am having is how to reference these tabs after they have been created. I feel like there is a simple syntax solution.

Comment: Are there any other suggestions? All that I really need here is to be able to iterate the name of a member of QTabWidget.

Comment: How have the tabs been created? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Store the pointers to tabs in an array and index it with the variable that you use for iterating over the third dimension of your multidimensional array of checkboxes, your code would look something like this:

```
QTabWidget* tabs[3];
tabs[0] = ui->dim1;
tabs[1] = ui->dim2;
tabs[2] = ui->dim3;

// ... and then

checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( tabs[z] ));
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my issue. This is a clean way of storing the tabs, but I am still unable to iterate through the name of the tabs here. Keep in mind that I have an unknown number of tabs, so I would still have to resort back to using my 'ui->tab_name' solution (which doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Someone will say it better (there is a concept name for that) but you can't dynamically declare members in c++ ... if you want `QString tab_name` content to be in any way related to a member of `ui` in this part of code:

```
QString tab_name = dim.append(QString("%1").arg(num));
checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( ui->tab_name ));
```

The compiler *need* to know at compile time witch member of `ui` it will use to find the parent of the the new `QCheckBox`.

Correct me if I am wrong, you have `dimz` tabs and `dimy*dimx` `QcheckBox` in each tabs. You don't know any `dim*` when you build you `ui` file ?

So create your own widget (`QWidget`) it will store an array of `QcheckBox*` that you can dynamically create in constructor for example. This widget will take care of the proper layout of the check boxes.

Then finally you create you own `QTabWidget` that will create `dimz` tabs of your widget. You will access your tabs with their indexes corresponding to their `z` coordinate.

Comment: With this solution, it will solve the problem of getting the check boxes to lay out properly; however, would I not also have to create a new array (or at least another dimension of checkBoxVector) to hold the checkboxes in? What I mean is that I need to be able to access the state of every check box later on in the code, and if I am simply copying the same array z times from the same widget, I would need to create a new array of check boxes for each tab regardless if I want to be able to access them. So I'm kind of back to the same point where I am currently in the code.

Comment: Not saying that separating data from `ui` is not a better option here but you can easily create a convenient accessor let name it `QCheckBox* getCheckBox(int x, int y, int z)` in your tab widget that will return the `dimx + y*dimy` `QCheckBox` of the tab with index `z` ...

Comment: The thing is that I have already created the tabs earlier on in the code, the only real problem that I have is simply trying to reference them by name using my 'for' loop. I feel like there is a simple syntax solution that I am missing. Sorry, I edited my question to give a bit more information, as I think I forgot to mention this!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference a member variable that does not exist:

```
int num = k+1;
QString dim = "dim";
QString tab_name = dim.append(QString("%1").arg(num));
checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( ui->tab_name ));
```

The error is caused by the fact that you are passing a non-existing member variable to the constructor of QCheckBox. The object the ui pointer is pointing to has no member variable named tab_name. If I understood your description correctly, just pass the local variable tab_name to the QCheckBox constructor like this:

```
checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( tab_name ));
```

Comment: This solution causes each check box to be created in its own separate window, with a label beside it that reads whatever is held in the tab_name variable. So say I create an array of 2*3*2 check boxes, it just pops up 12 windows with a single check box in each one.